How to set query string using WebSocketConnector from quarkus-websockets-next?
Is it possible to set a query string using WebSocketConnector from quarkus-websockets-next? If not I would be glad to find a workaround.
My current line to create ws client connection is
webSocketConnector.baseUri(serverUri).connect()


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
